# How did String.Split change in Delphi Tokyo?

Tags: string, delphi, split

The following code example will compile in Delphi XE5 to Seattle (10.0).
In Delphi Tokyo (10.2) I get a compile error on the ExcludeEmpty parameter (E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ExcludeEmpty').

What is going wrong?

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
  var S : String ;
      SA : Tarray<String> ;
begin
  S := '1234 5678' ;
  SA := S.Split([' '], ExcludeEmpty)
end.
```

Comment: Compiles without error in in 10.2.3

Comment: In Delphi 11 the definition is compiled with `{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}` so you have to use `TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty`. Not sure of previous versions.

Comment: @Brian, Sorry. Rookie error. Found the right link now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old enum and the values `(None, ExcludeEmpty, ExcludeLastEmpty)` do not have prefixes like newer enums to avoid identifier collisions. Compiling with `{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}` forces the use of a scope to prevent issues with collisions.

```
 SA := S.Split([' '], TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty);
```

I don't know all of the versions of Delphi that use this option to compile this enum but Delphi 11 does.

Comment: @Frank You know, don't you, that you can mark an answer (to your question(s)) as correct answer by clicking green the checkmark beside the answer. Later, when you have gained some reputation you can also up/down-vote posts.